# Bash List Files after a specific file

Tags: bash, shell, ls

I want to run my program on all the files in a directory after a specific file using a bash script.

If I have a directory like:

```
fileA
fileB
fileC
fileD
```

I want to run `./prog <file>` for all files after `fileC`. How would I write a bash script to do this?

I currently have

```
for FILE in ./tests/*; do
  ./prog $FILE
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "success: $FILE"
  else
    echo "**FAILURE: $FILE"
    exit 1
  fi
done
```

But, I want to start at a specific file in that directory. It doesn't necessarily need to be sorted since `ls` list files in a specific order which is the same each time.

I typically just run my script, and when it fails, I fix it for that specific file, but then I'd want to resume from that file, and not restart from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the files are sorted, then you can use `'<'` and `'>'` operators to do a stringwise compare of two variables:

```
startfile=$1
for FILE in ./tests/*; do
    if ! [ "$FILE" '<' "$startfile" ] ; then
        echo doing something with $FILE
    else
        echo Skipping $FILE
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in `ls tests | grep -A 999999 "^tests/startfile$" | tail -n +2`
do
  whatever
done
```

grep -A 999999 lists tests/startfile (^ and $ to avoid partial match) and the 999999 next entries.

tail -n +2 lists everything starting from line 2 (1-based)